# How can I find specific chat room in mobile web?

Tags: support, feature-request, search, chat, mobile-web

Is there a search feature in mobile web to search chat rooms ?

Ex: How can I find *Kotlin* chat room ? (Without exploring pagination links one by one)

Comment: If it's in your favourites you can open the "favorite" tab, otherwise I'd recommend just switching to the full site mode, searching, and then switching back to mobile mode after joining

Comment: @Nick there is no search bar in the favorite tab. Thank you very much for the suggestion :)

Comment: I know there's no search bar, but I meant that generally your favourites will be short enough to be able to see it if you've *previously* added it to your favourites, rather than having to go through the pages :)

Comment: Not exactly mobile chat web, but most browsers have a "Show desktop site" button as a part of the browser settings. It'll let you quickly enable it for the navigation portion, but the short answer is that there isn't a search bar in the mobile variant. As for the feature request aspect of it, eh... Chat hasn't been actively developed in _years_ (along with the mobile apps, just with the main exception that the apps are completely abandoned). We'll have to do with hackish workarounds of various types until it is, unfortunately.